# Problems reading data from a table

Tags: java, mysql, database, jpa, jdbc

Sorry if this is a newbie question.

If I've a table in my database called Settings with mostly columns of type long and I'm returning the last row in the table to a variable called results with this statement:

```
List results = em.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Settings s ORDER BY s.idsettings DESC").setMaxResults(1).getResultList();
```

It gives me an array of type Vector with each index holding a Settings array. How do I get access to the data in the Settings array? https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDva0.png

I need to get the column data and store them as longs in my java program so I can work with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It gives me an array of type Vector with each index holding a Settings **array**

No, as shown in your debugger, it returns a Vector that only contains one element (the one you want).

Just retrieve that object and use getters to read its columns.

```
Settings settings = (Settings)results.get(0);
long batLow = settings.getBatLow();
long batUp = settings.getBatUp();
...
```

Comment: Cool, but Settings settings = results.get(0); gives me the compiler error "incompatible types required Settings, found Object" what should I do?

Comment: oh it was just a simple cast -- settings = (Settings) results.get(0); thanks for your help